# Configure Firewall settings for local and public network

Tags: sql-server, firewall, port, windows-server-2012, azure

I have a VM on windows azure that is running an SQL server 2012 on windows datacenter 2012,

I want to define a firewall rule so that the sql server can be accessed from anywhere in the private network (azure virtual network) and from specific IPs adresses in the internet.

I tried to define that in the firewall as one could think it should be but still i get no access from anywhere,

Later on i discovered that i should play a bit with the sql server tcp/ip properties on the sql server network configurations/ protocols for sql server

I tried to play with all those properties but could only reach a situation which the sql server can be accessed from anywhere or cannot be accessed at all.

Can one tell me a step-by-step what should be the best way to solve this issue ?

Thanks.

EDIT :

After a lot of efforts i found the solution which contains 2 parts :

a. i needed to define via azure powershell the tcp endpoint for the sql because if its done via the portal it automatically defines it a load-balance port checks and than the load balance ip needs also to be enabled in the firewall.

b. i needed to open access to the udp port of 1434 because the sql server uses it to tell the end-user on which port it should set the communication

The endpoint acl is also an option

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of resources (blob posts, articles, etc.) that talk about setting up firewalls, so I'll skip that one. More interesting (to me) is allowing (or blocking) traffic from the Internet.

Last week, at TechEd, a new *endpoint ACL* feature was introduced (it's in production; this isn't preview). With it, you can specify IP ranges to allow (or block) on a given endpoint. IP ranges are specified in CIDR format. And today, the functionality is exposed through PowerShell.

Michael Washam blogged about this, [here](http://michaelwasham.com/windows-azure-powershell-june-2013-update-for-iaas-and-paas/).

Comment: Microsoft support has told me about the endpoint acl but they say its on preview...